# Change sepecific character values in entire column in RStudio

Tags: r

I have multiple columns of data with values of true and false. I would like to go through each column and change the values so that they say '[column title] true' or '[column title] false' instead of just true and false.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible exxample and expected output for that example

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, the OP may want to format the logical columns by inserting the column name of that column.  Assuming that it is needed for all the columns loop `across` all (`everything()`) the columns, use `sprintf` to format by inserting the column name (`cur_column()`) along with the value of the column after converting to `character` class

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), 
        ~ sprintf('[%s] %s', cur_column(), as.character(.))))
```

If it is only for logical columns, specify a logical expression within `where`

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.logical), 
        ~ sprintf('[%s] %s', cur_column(), as.character(.))))
```